# Poller spring integration behavior - windows v/s unix

Tags: cron, spring-integration

I am running a poller inside inbound-channel-adapter .
I noticed some differences in execution when poller has a cron attached:

int:poller cron = 0 */10 * * * *

Expected is as soon as poller loads, it picks all files available in directory provided and then tries again after 10 minutes:

- On Windows - All files are picked available no matter what count is and next execution comes after 10 minutes.
- On unix - It takes 10 minutes to poll each file.
  If first file is polled 09.00 , next is polled 09.10
  where as on windows, at 09.00 all files are picked and then again at 09.10.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Please, be more specific. 1. Share your config. 2. Describe the requirements. 3. What you mean with "picks all (or not all) files available". We may treat this logic a bit different rather than you. 4. Share some logs to point out when you don't like its behavior. Right now it is fully unclear what's problem. Such a functionality is there for a while already. And you first who doubts in that. So, you may just miss something...

Comment: Just wanted to be sure about file inbound adapter behavior. Say i have 100 files in a folder & frequency is 10 mins specified in poller. Will the adapter pick all 100 files in one go and come back after 10 mins or one file be picked every 10 mins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your terminology isn't clear for me.

Anyway: the `FileReadingMessageSource` scans target directory for files or on each poll or when an internal `Queue<File> toBeReceived` is empty (on the `poll`, too, of course). The `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` has `maxMessagesPerPoll` option, which is `1` by default. So, each poll task picks up one your file from the memory and sends to the channel. And yes, only after polling interval the next one is emitted.

You can configure `maxMessagesPerPoll = 0` and all the files in that `toBeReceived` will be send to the channel during one polling cycle.

See [Polling Message Source](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#_pollable_message_source) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Artem, You answered me, this is what i was looking for. :)